# Completing task involving 'dict'

Tags: python, task

Please help with the task. I tried to solve it myself, but nothing worked. I will be very grateful!

Task:

> The dictionary of the following kind is given:
> `numbers = {'a': [5,6,7], 'b': [9,8,3]}`
>
> Generate your dictionary on the same principle from 4 elements, generate numbers randomly.
> Print the largest sum of elements and their key.

Code:

```
import random
dict = {'a':random.randint(0, 10000000),
        'b':random.randint(0, 10000000),
        'c':random.randint(0, 10000000),
        'd':random.randint(0, 10000000),
        }
dict_1 = dict.values()
print(dict_1)
```

Comment: What do they mean by "from 4 elements"? The given dict only has 2 keys and 3 elements per list.

Comment: Please describe what part of the task is giving you problems and why.

Comment: I don't understand what "the same principle from 4 elements" is supposed to mean. Should there be 4 keys, 4 values, 4 keys+values, something else? If it refers to keys/values, then what about the values/keys? Since you only need to print the larget sum, do you actually need an intermediate `dics`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's break this task down:

1. First we need to create a dictionary with 4 lists of random numbers. I see that you already created a dict with 4 keys, so regarding generating the numbers' lists, this can help you - `random.sample(range(10, 30), 3)` (list of 3 elements, each one between 10-30).
2. You need to calculate the sum of each list, and remember the key with the highest sum. This can be done by simple iteration over the dict.

Suggestion:

```
import random

dict = {'a': random.sample(range(10, 30), 3),
        'b': random.sample(range(10, 30), 3),
        'c': random.sample(range(10, 30), 3),
        'd': random.sample(range(10, 30), 3),
        }
maximum_sum = 0
maximum_key = None
for key in dict:
    current_sum = sum(dict[key])
    if current_sum > maximum_sum:
        maximum_key = key
        maximum_sum = current_sum
print('{}: {}'.format(maximum_key, maximum_sum))
```

Comment: Since you already use `sum`, why not directly use `max` to replace the entire loop-and-pre-initiailzed-variables block?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it's just a straight forward suggestion...In addition he said that he needs also the key, so simple max is not enough